# How to put <security:authentication property="principal.username"/> inside a value=" " in an input?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-security

does anyone have an idea how I can put this line

```
<security:authentication property="principal.username"/>
```

inside  the  `value=""`

```
<form:input path="contactName" cssClass="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter your Contact Name please." value=""/>
```

If i keep it like in the code shown beneath, the username is shown underneath the input field and not within (obv).

```
 <form:input path="contactName" cssClass="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter your Contact Name please." value=""/>
            <security:authentication property="principal.username"/>
```

Much appreciate for any help!

With regards Niko

Answer (score 1):

Do you using Thymeleaf?

If yes, you can do like this.

Add `pom.xml` Dependency：

```xml
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then:

```html
<!-->it is necessary<-->
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">

<input placeholder="XXX" th:value="${#authentication.getName()}" />
```

It can get the username, but it will return `anonymousUser` even if you are not logged in.
Don't worry, this is a little problem, you can use thymeleaf's judgment expression.

You can find more detailed documentation at:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html

*If this doesn't solve your problem, I will follow up.*

Comment: Sry, i forgot to mention, im just using the "standard" mvc security dependencies, i have no idea about thymleaf :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Standard Spring-MVC, then you can send the username from the controller itself.

In the controller file, use Principal as the parameter. Use getName() of Principal class to set the username in model and pass it as return statement.

```java
    public ModelAndView display(Principal principal){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("uname", principal.getName());
        return mav;
    }
```

In the JSP file, use  `value="${uname}"`:

```html
    <form:input path="contactName" cssClass="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter your Contact Name please." value="${uname}"/>
```